# PHP Call to External Database

Tags: php, database

I am using the Sleek child theme from Studio Press and want to do a PHP call to this external database for it to display just like this link: http://www.escort332.org/tuskegeecadets.php . The Theme page is this full width page: http://escort332.org/wordpress1/tusk...skegee-cadets/. Is there a way to add the PHP code that links to the database in the page itself? I would also need access the database for other pages as well. Is this possible in the Genesis framework or child themes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I can't bee too specific answering your question, but you can certainly use a [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) instance to [access another database](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pros-and-cons-of-adding-tables-to-the-wp-db?replies=8#post-1201613):

```
$db = new wpdb('user', 'password', 'dbname', 'dbhost');
$results = $db->get_results('..query..');
```

Comment: Hey!, how did you `wpdb` instance from.. did you call it from headers or any other thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/* get the database configuration automatically starts here */

$server_url = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$doc_root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

require($doc_root . '/wp-config.php');


$post_id = 5;


query_posts( 'p=' . $post_id );

global $more;
$more = 0;

// the Loop
while (have_posts()) : 
    the_title();
    the_content( 'Read the full post »' );
endwhile;



?>
```

I have tried  and got the solution.